Failed to transform jetified-koin-core-jvm-3.5.3.jar to match attributes
When building a build for android, an error pops up:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:dexBuilderRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':launcher:detachedConfiguration5'.
   > Failed to transform jetified-koin-core-jvm-3.5.3.jar to match attributes {artifactType=ext-dex-dexBuilderRelease, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingExternalLibArtifactTransform: /Users/warboss/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/05528e14a870f120c05ff234a90e042e/jetified-koin-core-jvm-3.5.3.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform jetified-koin-annotations-jvm-1.3.0.jar to match attributes {artifactType=ext-dex-dexBuilderRelease, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingExternalLibArtifactTransform: /Users/warboss/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/6a9a76c3967850c14ee1489439eb3f70/jetified-koin-annotations-jvm-1.3.0.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.21.jar to match attributes {artifactType=ext-dex-dexBuilderRelease, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingExternalLibArtifactTransform: /Users/warboss/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/3394a5c219b81cc8a53f15306d13e2f8/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.21.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

What could be the reason? The error appeared after updating the Applovin Max plugin.
Unity 2021.3.36
Applovin Max 6.5.2
Gradle - 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
